# How to add a token to an existing language (e.g. typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I can define tokens with setMonarchTokensProvider, but that does not really help because I can only make a new language or overwrite typescript. In either case I do not have the rest of the typescript tokens which I still want to have.

I just want to add one token, which will have a specific meaning in the context of this editor, which I want to colorize. While still having all of typescript.

This is what I have till now (taken form the playground examples), but with this the rest of typescript is gone:

```
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('typescript', {
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/\pvm.*/, "custom-error"]
        ]
    }
});


monaco.editor.defineTheme('myCoolTheme', {
    base: 'vs',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [
        { token: 'custom-error', foreground: 'ff0000', fontStyle: 'bold' }
    ]
});
```

(And then using theme myCoolTheme when creating the editor)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the language .js file and adding the customization there. Not the way I'd like to do it, but it works.

Comment: I thought about that as well. For various reasons (like e.g. update-ability) it is really more of an ugly workaround than a solution. For a lack of a real solution till now: Have my up-vote. But I struggle to accept this as a doable solution.

Comment: I've been fighting this for days, even opened an issue on the Monaco GitHub which has yet to be resolved: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3448. The documentation is absolutely in shambles, no idea what is going on at Microsoft.

Comment: @ctsears - would you mind sharing where you found all the language.js files? Ideally I'll need this for typescript, javascript, python, etc.